# Packages installation and files not saved on Alpine VM after reboot

Tags: virtualbox, alpine-linux

I want to create some Alpine VMs in VirtualBox.

To do so, I first downloaded both the Standard and the Virtual versions (see https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/), and then I created two **vdi** from their .iso with `VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI alpine-standard-3.10.3-x86_64.iso vm_1.vdi`.

Finally, I created both machines in VirtualBox with the two **vdi**. Everything ok.

However, if I install a package or simply `vi hello.txt` in the folder after log in, after reboot, everything is gone. The installed packages, the new files created by me...

Why does this happen? Why is nothing persistent?

**note:** I've originally wanted to install the Extended version, but I changed my mind when I read that it "runs from RAM" and I associated it with "everything is wiped after reboot", but I may be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've missed [a step](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation):

> Now Alpine are complete running from the media source, you can install it by running the [`setup-alpine`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setup-alpine) command.
>
> Before runs `setup-alpine` there's many ways and use cases in the [Alpine install manual for beginners](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_newbie_install_manual#Ways_to_install_Alpine_into_machines_or_virtuals)

What you've actually done is to create a virtual hard drive that is a byte-for-byte copy of the ISO file intended to be burned to a CD.  You're effectively booting Alpine Linux as a [Live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS).

The file system on the ISO is [ISO9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) and Linux will mount this in read-only mode. When this boots, a clever trick is used with a [ram-disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) and [overlayfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS). This gives the impression of being read-writable.  In fact all changes are just stored in RAM.

---

You need to actually install alpine, rather than run it as a Live-CD.  To do this:

- create a new VM with a fresh *empty* VDI image as a hard drive.
- add the ISO file as a CD (insert CD)
- ensure the VM's boot priority boots from CD first
- boot up the VM
- inside this run `setup-alpine`
- shutdown
- remove the ISO (eject CD)
- boot up the VM
- add your packages as you did before

Comment: There is also good description at https://linuxhint.com/install-alpine-linux-virtualbox/